# Error: (root) Additional property laminas is not allowed

Tags: docker, docker-compose, laminas

I keep getting this error every time I execute docker-compose up -d command in Windows CLI. Please help me solve this problem. Docker-compose.yml file which I'm using is part of Laminas skeleton application and was prewritten there.
Here is docker-compose.yml code:

```
laminas:
  build: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
  ports:
   - "8081:80"
  volumes:
   - .:/var/www
```

Here is Dockerfile code:

```
FROM php:7.3-apache

LABEL maintainer="getlaminas.org" \
    org.label-schema.docker.dockerfile="/Dockerfile" \
    org.label-schema.name="Laminas MVC Skeleton" \
    org.label-schema.url="https://docs.getlaminas.org/mvc/" \
    org.label-schema.vcs-url="https://github.com/laminas/laminas-mvc-skeleton"

## Update package information
RUN apt-get update

## Configure Apache
RUN a2enmod rewrite \
    && sed -i 's!/var/www/html!/var/www/public!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf \
    && mv /var/www/html /var/www/public

## Install Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer \
  | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

###
## PHP Extensisons
###

## Install zip libraries and extension
RUN apt-get install --yes git zlib1g-dev libzip-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip

## Install intl library and extension
RUN apt-get install --yes libicu-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure intl \
    && docker-php-ext-install intl

WORKDIR /var/www
```

Comment: Is that the whole file?  Usually I'd expect to see `version:` and `services:` at the top level, and a block like this underneath 'services:`.

Comment: Yes, that is the whole file. I've just started to learn Laminas MVC framefork. And I don't understand that type of syntax as well. So I expected someone to explain this to me. I can add Dockerfile code, if you need more information.

Comment: [Overview of Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) in the Docker documentation might be a good starting point.  (It looks like Compose might have removed support for the old v1 Compose file format without `services:`.)

Comment: The thing is that I had everything working on the different machine with the same setup (forgot to mention that, my bad). That's why I'm curious what did happen on this one.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else new to Docker, you want to do

```yaml
services: # Add this
  laminas:
    build: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
     - "8081:80"
    volumes:
     - .:/var/www
```